# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyautogui (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pyautogui

I tried to import my module.
I put this in Jupyter notebook

```
! pip install pyautogui
```

the output is

```
could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyautogui/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyautogui/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping




WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pyautogui/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pyautogui/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyautogui (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyautogui
```

how can i get rid of this problem? Please help..

Answer (score 0):

If you have both python2 and python3 it is best to use pip3 and sometimes even if python2 is not installed errors may happen with pip

So replace `! pip install pyautogui`  with `! pip3 install pyautogui`  and it should work